# How can I put elements underneath each other in flex display?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

Here is my code:

```css
.menu_box {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 60vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.menu_box_body {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width:100%;
}

.menu_box_header {
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu_options {
  border: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="menu_box">
  <div class="menu_box_header">
  </div>
  <div class="menu_box_body">
    <div class="menu_options col-xs-6"><div>{icon}</div><h3>part1</h3></div>
    <div class="menu_options col-xs-6"><div>{icon}</div><h3>part2</h3></div>
    <div class="menu_options col-xs-6"><div>{icon}</div><h3>part3</h3></div>
    <div class="menu_options col-xs-6"><div>{icon}</div><h3>part4</h3></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to put `{icon}` in the top of `partN` *(not next to each `partN`)*. how can I do that? As you know, both `<div>` and `<h3>` has `block` display. But I really don't know why they are next to each other. Anyway, how can I put them underneath each other?

Comment: You'll need to declare `flex-direction: column;` on `.menu_options`. Since `.menu_options` has been set to `display: flex;`, nested elements are laid out according to the *flexbox model* regardless of what display type you have set for these children elements. So in other words, you'll still need to define the *direction* of the children of the flex container.

Answer (score 23):

If you replace .menu_box_body css below two lines

```css
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

with below two lines

```css
flex-direction: column;
align-items:center;
```

You will get the result. Final CSS will be:

```css
.menu_box_body {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items:center;
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have added display flex to the .menu_options element, which refers to the cell. This is why the elements are not acting as blocks as  If you remove display flex there, they will stack on top of each other.

If you still want to use display:flex there (e.g. to center stuff) you can add flex-direction: column - that will also put them on top of each other.

Comment: If I remove `display:flex;`, then the items will not be center (vertically) anymore.

Comment: I have expanded on my answer to address this.